# How to get sever based id from AutoCompleteText values loading from external database

Tags: android, sql, autocompletetextview

I have implemented an `AutoCompleteTextView` and populating the values from the external database.  What I want to do is when a value is clicked, I want to get the `Id` of the value same as in the server.

So, if `Injection` `Id` is 72 in the external database, When I click it in my android app, i get 72 as id.

So far I have tried the following code howeever its giving me the position not the id.

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), list2.get(position).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                Object data = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                int realPosition = list2.indexOf(data);
                String str_realPositionMode = String.valueOf(realPosition);
                 Log.d("Chek id for autocomplete",str_realPositionMode);

            }
```

Retriving data using JSON:

```
try
    {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://datanetbeta.multi-trade.co.uk/tablet/appModelNames.php");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("Pass 1", "connection success ");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }     

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("Pass 2", "connection success ");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
    }     

   try{
        JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json= null;
        final String[] str2 = new String[JA.length()]; 

        for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
        {
            json=JA.getJSONObject(i);
            str2[i] = json.getString("appliances_models_id");     // retrieving id
            str2[i]=json.getString("appliances_models_name");
        }
        final List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<str2.length;i++)
        {
            list2.add(str2[i]);
        }
        Collections.sort(list2);

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.app_mod_auto_com , list2);

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        auto_complete_app_model.setThreshold(1);
        auto_complete_app_model.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Do you get that id from the external database when you retrieve the actual data?

Comment: Please see my update for retrieving data

Comment: `appliances_models_id` is the id to which you are referring?

Comment: Yes, I want to retrieve and display that in my `TextView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you parse the server results you seem to use the same array `str2` for both the id and the name. A simple solution(if you don't modify the data) would be to use another `List` to hold the ids which will replicate the current name `List`:

```
final List<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
final List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(); // why aren't you using a List directly?
for(int i=0 ; i < JA.length(); i++) {
     json=JA.getJSONObject(i);
     idList.add(json.getInt("appliances_models_id")); // you said this is a int
     list2.add(json.getString("appliances_models_name"));
}
```

Then in the `OnItemClickListener` you could simply do:

```
int theId = idList.get(position);
```

The proper solution would be to create a custom class to hold both pieces of data

```
class Appliance {
    int id;
    String name;    

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // this is the method that will be called by the adapter
        return name;
    }
}
```

which you could use like:

```
final List<Appliance> list2 = new ArrayList<Appliance>(); 
for(int i=0 ; i < JA.length(); i++) {
     Appliance item = new Appliance();
     json=JA.getJSONObject(i);
     item.id = json.getInt("appliances_models_id")); // you said this is a int
     item.name = json.getString("appliances_models_name");  
     list2.add(item);
}
ArrayAdapter<Appliance> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Appliance>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.app_mod_auto_com , list2);
```

In the `OnItemClickListener` you'll have:

```
Appliance item = (Appliance) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
// use the item.id to do what you want.
```

Comment: What if the data need to be modified in the future ?

Comment: @user3807650 You use the second approach with a custom class, that way you have the id and name together.

Comment: Thanks dude.. you save me a lot of hours :)